# Ion-Toggle After Refresh it has to get data back from local storage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

So i have a problem.
My goal is: I made a Black/Light Theme in my app. So whenever i click the toggle the theme of the app changes to black and if i refresh it stays black and if i turn it back to OFF it turns back to light and it stays on light. But my struggle is whenever i refresh the page the toggle doesn't stay on the current state as ON -> black theme and OFF -> Light Theme

So ON -> Black Theme
   OFF -> Light Theme

Settings.HTML

```
<ion-item>>
    <ion-label>Light/Dark</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="lightDark" [checked]="" (ionChange)="toggleAppTheme()"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

Settings.TS

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            public navParams: NavParams,
            private settings: SettingsProvider) {
    this.settings.getActiveTheme().subscribe(val => this.selectedTheme = val);

    console.log("Toggled: "+ this.lightDark);
}

toggleAppTheme() {
    if (this.selectedTheme == 'light-theme') {

        this.settings.setActiveTheme('dark-theme');
        localStorage.setItem("themeColor", this.selectedTheme);

    } else if (this.selectedTheme == 'dark-theme') {

        this.settings.setActiveTheme('light-theme');
        localStorage.setItem("themeColor", this.selectedTheme);

    }
}
```

App.Component.ts

```
 // Dark/Light Mode
    if(localStorage.getItem("themeColor") == "dark-theme")
    {

        this.settings.setActiveTheme("dark-theme");


    }
    else if(localStorage.getItem("themeColor") == "light-theme")
    {

        this.settings.setActiveTheme("light-theme");

    }
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this question?

Answer (score 1):

The `ion-toggle` component is bound to the `lightDark` property, but I don't see you're setting its initial value when initializing the page:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            public navParams: NavParams,
            private settings: SettingsProvider) {

    this.settings.getActiveTheme().subscribe(
        val => {
            this.selectedTheme = val;

            // Initialize the state of the toggle
            // It should be true if the theme is the dark one, right?
            this.lightDark = this.selectedTheme === 'dark-theme';     

            // Show the value in the console to see if it works 
            console.log("Toggled: "+ this.lightDark);       
        },
        error => {
            // Handle the error...
        });
}
```